# Sequences of $0$ and $1$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

How many is sequences with length $4n$ which contain only $0$ and $1$.
 $0$ occurs $2n$ times and $1$ occurs $2n$ times. Moreover number of occurs $0$ before $n$'th occur of $1$ can't be bigger than $n$

### My attempt

I thought that I can use there generating functions. So let assume that we have put our  $"1"$ and now we want to put $0$ between them.

$$[x^{2n}] (1+x)(1+x+x^2)\cdot...\cdot(1+x+x^2+...+x^{2n})$$
Each fraction represents how many zeros we can put before $i'th$ $1$. 
$$[x^{2n}] \frac{(1-x^2)(1-x^4)...(1-x^{2n})}{(1-x)^{2n}}$$
$$[x^{2n}] (1-x^2)(1-x^4)...(1-x^{2n}) \cdot \sum_{0\le k}\binom{k+2n-1}{2n-1}x^k$$

But I don't know how I can find $[x^{2n}]$ there

Comment: These are called "Dyck Words" and they are counted by the [Catalan Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)

Comment: @lulu so the answer is $c_{2n} = \frac{(4n)!}{(2n+1)!\,(2n)!}$ ? I am not sure about combinatorics interpretation of that.

Comment: The catalan numbers aren't all that intuitive...it's not even obvious that $\frac 1{n+1}\binom {2n}{n}$ is an integer.  The wiki article should offer some useful leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the position of the nth 1. Should it be larger than or equal to $2n$?

Solution:

The position of nth 1 should not be larger than or equal to $2n$. Otherwise, among the first $2n-1$ elements, there are $n-1$ 1's and $n$ 0
s.

Then you can freely distribute the first $2n-1$ positions with $n$ 1's and $n - 1$ 0s. Now, I think you can derive the answer yourself.